# How to parse the byte string with key=value format in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
from subprocess import PIPE,run
....
....
log=run([myCmd,cwd='/my/dir',stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
```

Now `log` has got value as below:

```
b'owner=mike\ntitle=clean\nmiles=120k\nlocation=tx\n'
```

What is the best way to parse and get the value I am interested in, e.g, I like to get the value of `miles` which is `120k`. I use python3

Answer (score 0):

Decode it, then abuse the fact that `dict` accepts an iterable:

```
string = b'owner=mike\ntitle=clean\nmiles=120k\nlocation=tx\n'
string = string.decode()
print(dict(key_value.split('=') for key_value in string.split('\n') if key_value))
# {'owner': 'mike', 'title': 'clean', 'miles': '120k', 'location': 'tx'}
```

From here the way to any arbitrary value is as easy as accessing a dictionary key:

```
d = dict(key_value.split('=') for key_value in string.split('\n') if key_value)
print(d['miles'])
# 120k
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go,

```
 _dict = {}
 f = b'owner=mike\ntitle=clean\nmiles=120k\nlocation=tx\n'
[_dict.update({e.split("=")[0]: e.split("=")[1]} ) for e in f.decode().split("\n") if e]
```

For value of miles, you can do

```
_dict["miles"]
```